# How can i add some sql to all querys in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I want a version control system and therefore all querys must add a piece of sql

In place for the current record shows.

But what place, can i add that piece of sql to all querys ?
or could i do it with events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a class that implements IInterceptor

then give that class as param to the session like

```
SessionManager.SessionFactory.OpenSession(new newClass()));
```

in the class you need to give your implementation to

```
public NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString OnPrepareStatement(NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString sql)
{

}
```

each query that will run on this session will be intercept here and there you can add some sql