# Control the way nhibernate does querying

Tags: nhibernate

I've experienced a couple of days ago, that a problem with the name of the fields in the final query. It was a bug from a version before the 2.0.GA.
To not drag too long on this, it was a problem when the query is too big, and you use SetMaxResults altogether. It got me a though:
**Would there any way to control how NHibernate is going to name your fields in the SQL query?**
Because as I have seen for a while, and in this case more than ever, the relathionship between tables and the naming convention for the fields that will be rendered whit a not so pretty as I exaustly set on my criteria.

Comment: What do you mean? The SQL is generated using your mapping. You'll need to post more information on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question, yes, you could implement an IInterceptor to change anything in the generated SQL. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287943/how-can-i-add-some-sql-to-all-querys-in-nhibernate).

However, that's very likely not the way to fix your problem...

Comment: Indeed... But it answered my question, i guess thats enough. Thank you